# Generating a Concordion summary report

Tags: acceptance-testing, concordion

My project is looking at using Concordion to do automated acceptance tests.  The big lack I'm seeing in Concordion is an automatically-generated summary page.  As it stands we would have to have a tester or functional user dig into each of the generated HTML pages to check for success or failure.

In looking at Concordion's svn repository I see one proposed modification to generate a summary XML file -- but that change hasn't been incorporated into the trunk line as far as I can tell.  I would rather avoid cracking Concordion's source open and modifying it directly, if I can.

Is anybody aware of a quick & dirty way to generate a Concordion master/summary report type page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Definitely late reply for your question but this might help others who end up in this question.

We use **concordion:run="concordion"** feature to generate a meaningful summary page.

As you can see below we have the initial Customer.html file invoking other Customer flow concordion scripts.

**Customer.html**

```
<html xmlns:concordion="http://www.concordion.org/2007/concordion">
<head>
<title>Customer</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class='testcontent'>
        <h1>Customer</h1>
        <h3>Customer flows:</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a concordion:run="concordion" href="CreateNewCustomer.html">Create New Customer</a></li>
            <li><a concordion:run="concordion" href="ModifyCustomer.html">Modify Customer</a></li>
            <li><a concordion:run="concordion" href="DeleteCustomer.html">Delete Customer</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Customer.java**

```
@RunWith(ConcordionRunner.class)
public class SpecsTest{
}
```

CreateNewCustomer.html, ModifyCustomer.html and DeleteCustomer.html files will have the actual specification with **Given, When, Then**.

When we run CustomerTest.java, all these three flows get executed and Customer.html summary page
will show all three specs as Red or Green based on whether it was a success or failure.

We have multiple levels of grouping Spec file like these and we end up with a good summary page.

Comment: Is it possible to get the report on a single page. Rather than drilling down on each link and finding which test case failed and which one passed?

Answer (score 0):

Just getting started myself, but it seems like the purpose of the html pages is to document what is being tested. The tests are run as junit tests and the results can be captured with whatever harness you already use.

A summary page would be nice, but it isn't necessary to determine if there are any failures.